# Requests module bugging

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I am trying to test my API with post request and it works ONLY with thunder client. When I try with python module requests, it returns me this error :

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=2222): Max retries exceeded with url: /test_verification (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001FA618F72E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée'))
```

here is my code :

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://127.0.0.1:2222/test_verification'
>>> data = {"first_name":"ayoub", "last_name":"semsar","gender":"M", "age":"16", "country":"France", "e_mail":"password@yahoo.com", "password":"password"}
>>> headers = {"Content-type":"application/json", "Accept":"text/plain"}
>>> res = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Is there something running on `127.0.0.1:2222` ?

Comment: Have you tried `res = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)` ? Presumably without `headers=` too (note the `json=` parameter)

Comment: @AndrejKesely it didn't work as well, it returned me the same error